# Remove contents of an array from another array

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I have two arrays

```
var array1 = new Array ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e"];
var array2 = new Array ["a", "c", "d"];
```

I want to remove elements of array2 from array1

Result `["b", "e"]`

Is there anything like

```
array1 = array1.remove(array2)
```

Note I'm using jquery-1.9.1

Comment: possible duplicate of [JavaScript array difference](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1187518/javascript-array-difference)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try:

```
var diff = $(array1).not(array2).get();
```

Comment: When it try this output is '[1, 2, 6, diff: function]' How to remove that 'diff: function' from that?

Comment: Looks okay on fiddle, http://jsfiddle.net/nKNdA/ , try your data here and update, send the link please.

Answer (score 2):

```
function difference(source, toRemove) {
    return source.filter(function(value){
        return toRemove.indexOf(value) == -1;
    });
}
```

**NOTE**: `Array.prototype.indexOf` and `Array.prototype.filter` are not available before **IE9**!

Answer (score 1):

Although lot of ways to achieve it through native java script but i recommend to see [Underscore library](http://underscorejs.org/#difference)

Answer (score 1):

Underscore JS is what you need. This library has lots of useful array manipulation functions.
[Underscore JS](http://underscorejs.org/)

Answer (score 0):

Underscore.js library helps: Hers is what you need

```
_.difference(array1, array2);
```